# creating a do while loop that can end whenever a specific user input is given

Tags: c#, arrays

I am attempting to create a program that makes receipts for people. The console will ask for the item name, price, and quantity; following this it should print out the array (formatted hopefully). But the issue here is I am stuck on trying to figure out how to break the array naturally. As I am supposed to end the loop when a user inputs 0 but I cannot find a way to put that into a boolean statement.

Ive checked the Microsoft documentation and have not been able to find a solution to this specific problem. I also checked here but to no avail.

```
public class InitArray
{
    // create and output rectangular and jagged arrays
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[,] items = new string[100, 4];
        do
        {

            for (int row = 0; row < items.GetLength(0); row++)
            {
                // loop through columns of current row
                double price = 0;
                double subtotal = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("Item Name(enter 0 to stop): ");
                items[row, 0] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Item Price(enter 0 to stop): ");
                items[row, 1] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Quantity(enter 0 to stop): ");
                items[row, 2] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                items[row, 3] = Convert.ToString(price + subtotal);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(); // start new line of output

        }
        while ();
    } // end method OutputArray
} // end class InitArray
```

Comment: To break out of a loop you would use the **break** statement.

Comment: `break;` will exit from a loop, but to exit the `do` you would need to set a condition in your `while` that you can set inside the `for` loop before the `break;`. Not sure why you have a `do` loop around a `for` loop, though...

Comment: Do you want to close the console when you enter 0? Or just exit the for loop?

Comment: Where do you set the price and subtotal variables? In this code you will always set a zero

Answer (score 1):

You already have a loop with the for-Statement. You don't need an additional loop. Break out of the for-Loop by using `break` when the user has entered "0".

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string[,] items = new string[100, 4];

    for (int row = 0; row < items.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        // loop through columns of current row
        string input;

        Console.WriteLine("Item Name(enter 0 to stop): ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input == "0") break;
        items[row, 0] = input;

        Console.WriteLine("Item Price(enter 0 to stop): ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input == "0") break;
        items[row, 1] = input;

        Console.WriteLine("Quantity(enter 0 to stop): ");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input == "0") break;
        items[row, 2] = input;


        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a more convenient way to store your information. Better use a `List<Product>` instead of a bidimensional array. Using a List of a specific class  will allow you to not worry about array dimensions, but also will allow you to have all your data with a correct datatype and not a bunch of strings.

Your problem to stop the input whenever you get a "0" from your user could be solved with a generic function that returns a boolean if your user has requested to stop the inputs.

So first define a Product class

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    ... other field if you need them...
}
```

Now write a boolean function that signals the calling code the intention to stop the inputs

```
public bool getInput(string message, out string result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    result = Console.ReadLine();
    return (!result.Equals("0"))
}
```

In the function above, we return the input from the user in the out variable and if the user asks to stop we return false.

Now to put all together we could write this

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

bool ok = true;
while(ok)
{
    string input;
    Product p = new Product();
    ok = getInput("Item Name(enter 0 to stop): ", out input);
    if (ok) p.Name = input;
    if (ok) ok = getInput("Item Price(enter 0 to stop): ", out input);
    if (ok) p.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(input);
    if (ok) ok = getInput("Quantity(enter 0 to stop): ", out input);
    if (ok) { p.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(input); products.Add(p);}
}
decimal totalPrice = products.Sum(p => p.Price);
Console.WriteLine(totalPrice);
```

Comment: It might be easier to just break whenever getInput returns false instead of having every line check the value of ok.

Comment: I prefer to have a single exit point, but yes a break in a simple scenario like this is more than enough (And this approach removes the _else_ part giving a more linear flow but this is just my opinion)

Comment: Single exit points are nice but I don't believe in them as a hard-and-fast rule. I find it's generally best to exit a loop/function the moment you know you're done. That way, you don't need additional checks to ensure you still should be doing something - you just do it because if you shouldn't be there, you would have already exited. The end result is more efficient code and usually less nesting, which in turn results in more readable code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of @Steve you could also use logical ANDs.

```cs
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

while (getInput("Item Name(enter 0 to stop): ", out var name)
        && getInput("Item Price(enter 0 to stop): ", out var price)
        && getInput("Quantity(enter 0 to stop): ", out var quantity))
{
    products.Add(new Product
    {
        Name = name,
        Price = Convert.ToDecimal(price),
        Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(quantity)
    });
}
decimal totalPrice = products.Sum(p => p.Price);
Console.WriteLine(totalPrice);
```

Comment: even better, I like it